# All array value in object got updated in this.setState even when index is specify

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had a dynamic option form. When form type is selected, it will update the specific array type based on the array index. e.g: `this.state.menuInput = [{"title" : "array 1" , "type" : ""} , {"title" : "array 2" , "type" : ""}]`. When I change the form type of array 2 value, the type should be update to whatever is selected.

It should be in this format `[{"title" : "array 1" , "type" : ""} , {"title" : "array 2" , "type" : "radio_button"}]`. Currently when I'm mutating the state, the "type" is being updated in both array.

Like this:  `[{"title" : "array 1" , "type" : "radio_button"} , {"title" : "array 2" , "type" : "radio_button"}]`. Even when I specifically hard coded the array index in `setstate`.

How can I just mutate the array value based on the index?

```
 menuTypeOption(index, menuType){

    this.setState(prevState => {
        const newMenu = [...prevState.menuInput];
        newMenu[index]['title'] = menuType;
        return {menuInput: newMenu};
    } , function(){
        console.log(this.state.menuInput);
    })

}
```

Comment: You probably have the same object's reference in both indexes. Also, `newMenu` is a just shallow copy of the array. So, `newMenu[index]['title'] = menuType` mutates the state.

Comment: @adiga, Hi, even if its the same object reference but providing an index should only mutate the correct array object?

Comment: `let obj = { title: 1 }; let arr = []; arr.push(obj); arr.push(obj);` Now `arr` has the same object in both indices. If you update `arr[0].title = 2`, it updates the `title` both the indices, because they are both pointing the same object in memory

Comment: @adiga, yup. i get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this line `const newMenu = [...prevState.menuInput];` you don't make a deep copy of array, but only new array pointing to same objects.

So `newMenu[index]['title'] = menuType;` mutates original object.

Instead of mutating you can create new object with changed property:

```
newMenu[index] = {...newMenu[index], title: menuType};
```

---

In case there is already two pointers to same object in original array, then this solution works also, because it creates new object, and doesn't mutate shared object.

It can be demonstrated that way:

```
const obj = {foo: 'bar'};
let arr = [obj, obj]; // same object used twice
// now if we do `obj.foo = 'new value';`, it'll change both values in array
arr = [...arr];
arr[1] = {...arr[1], foo: 'new value'};
// now we have two different objects in arr: one points to old, and one points to new copy with changed values
```

Comment: That still doesn't explain why `title` of both indices get updated to `radio_button`

Comment: @adiga you're right. However solution still works for that case. Updated answer